# Wildcard vs SAN certificates

Tags: certificates

I have few questions regarding Wildcard vs SAN certificates.

Let’s say I’ve got a wildcard certificate for `*.example.com`, so the Wildcard certificate will cover all one level subdomains e.g. `owa.example.com`, `contact.example.com` etc. but it will not cover domains like `test.owa.example.com`.

It will not cover the main domain `example.com`, correct? 
But if one goes to my site via `www.example.com`, it will work without any certificate warning, correct?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)  says:

> The "naked" domain is valid when added separately as a Subject Alternative Name (SubjectAltName):[5]
>   •   example.com >

So how to call then this type of certificate? Wildcard SAN certificate? Does that mean that a Wildcard certificate can be a SAN certificate at the same time?

Also, if a wildcard certificate applies to a given domain, `example.com` in this case, can I include different domains e.g. `example.com`, `test.com`, `adam.com` in a SAN certificate?

Answer (score 4):

> if one goes to my site via www.example.com , it will work without any certificate warning , correct?

Yes.

> how to call then this type of certificate ? Wildcard SAN certificate?

Whatever marketing department comes up with.

There is no fixed term "SAN certificate" -- it is a shorthand, possessive expression: a certificate with the SAN extension defined.

> if a wildcard certificate applies to a given domain, `example.com` in this case, can I include different domains e.g. `example.com`, `test.com`, `adam.com` in a SAN [ ]

Yes, you can.

Comment: Thank you. So, in a Wildcard certificate the Issued to filed would be set to *.example.com. If I add test.com in Sub Alter Name Filed, will it then match everything , e.g. owa.test.com or only test.com ?

Comment: Only `test.com`.

Comment: And if I would include *.test.com in the SAN filed, that would behave basically the same way as the Wildcard for the example .com domain, correct ?

Comment: Yes, it would. Of course, provided the browser would support it, but most likely do.

Comment: One last question. Let's say, I try to access https://server1.prod.test.com but the certificate presented by the server contains *lab.thisistest.com in the Issued to filed, and exact the same value in the SAN filed, the browser will provide me with a warning ? Also, if the Issued to and SAN filed reflect the same value, this doesn't make much sense, correct? I would have to add *test.com in to the SAN filed or prod.test.com, correct ? If yes, I guess that this would required then a new certificate to be issued?

Comment: +1 for 'Whatever marketing department comes up with.'